# How rewrite my URIs with Zend_Router

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to create a Zend_Route in my application. Currently I have URIs like this:

```
/api/resource/index/id/123
```

And I would like to rewrite them with Zend_Router to:

```
/api/resource/123
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God I'm slow today. I have figured it out:

```
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/api/:controller/:id',
        array(
            'module'     => 'api',
            'action'     => 'index'
        )
    );

    $router->addRoute('resource', $route);
```

Comment: if you are slow only today it s fine brah. dont worry.